# CODEIGNITER - Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got the following message:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/usermodel.php

Line Number: 4146

and here is my function where the line 4146 is:

```
else if($resultRes->average<'3' &&  $resultRes->average>='2')
```

This is the full function code. I have the same message for line 4137, 4140, 4143, 4146 and 4149

```
function get_Ranking($resid=''){
$sql="select ((Qrating+Srating+Drating+Crating)/4) as average from testimonial where RestId=".$resid;
$query=$this->db->query($sql);
$resultRes=$query->row();
if($resultRes->average == '5'){
return '050';
}
else if($resultRes->average<'5' &&  $resultRes->average>='4'){
return '040';
}
else if($resultRes->average<'4' &&  $resultRes->average>='3'){
return '030';
}
else if($resultRes->average<'3' &&  $resultRes->average>='2'){
return '020';
}
else if($resultRes->average<'2' &&  $resultRes->average>='1'){
return '010';
}

else{
return '000';
}
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the records from the database properly

Answer (score 3):

It's because some of your queries are empty.

```
if($query->num_rows() != 0)
```

first

Comment: I was getting this warning & trying to find solution but no luck. Thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if($resultRes[0]['average'] == '5'){
    return '050';
}
else if($resultRes[0]['average'] < '5' &&  $resultRes[0]['average'] >= '4'){
    return '040';
}
```

Since it will return an single row only,You can either use `$resultRes['average']` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the $resultRes before getting average from it.

```
$resultRes=$query->row();
printr($resultRes);
```

also print the last query and check whether your parameters are correctly populated in the query using below query.

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

It can be the case your parameter is empty and no record retrieved from table.

Comment: It seems not working properly my function, because i write the print_r($resultRes); and it does´nt work, it does'nt show anything on my screen, i will review other files, because everything is ok in my database. Thanks anyway and i  will post later if i get some result.

Comment: Please check the query by using echo $this->db->last_query(); after running the query. Then you can execute the query directly and check what is the result returned.